# Regex wildcard and lookaround

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a roster of dates and want to capture the information from the date ( 01 Aug SA ) all the way to the beginning of the next date 
EG ( 31 Jul FR  0135  HKG MEL    33K  18:00  19:44       ) in the first instance and ( 01 Aug SA 06:40  07:10 11:10 ) in the next etc.

The regex I have is a look ahead, but I don't see how to do it.

```
regex:: $pattern = '/.*(?=\d{2}\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\w{2})/';
```

> 31 Jul FR  0135  HKG MEL    33K  18:00  19:44       01 Aug SA
>   06:40  07:10 11:10 02 Aug SU  0134  MEL HKG    33K  06:40  07:37 
>   15:21  15:51 11:11 03 Aug MO  G                 04 Aug TU  0905  HKG
>   MNL    330  20:50  22:52       05 Aug WE              00:58
>   0912  MNL HKG    330    08:32  10:36  11:06 14:16 06 Aug TH  T2024
>   P2    19:00  19:00       07 Aug FR              00:30  00:30 05:30
>   T2314    2R    22:00  22:00       08 Aug SA              06:00  06:00
>   08:00 09 Aug SU  G                 10 Aug MO  G                 11 Aug
>   TU  R13        06:00  06:00  06:06  06:06 00:06    0699  HKG BOM
>   33G  16:20  17:53  21:07  21:37 07:47 12 Aug WE                   13
>   Aug TH  RPT        00:00  00:00  02:45  02:45 02:45 14 Aug FR  0660 
>   BOM HKG    33G  03:05  04:15  12:48  13:18 07:43 15 Aug SA  R13
>   06:00  06:00  11:23  11:23 05:23    T1514    CW    14:00  14:00  19:30
>   19:30 05:30 16 Aug SU  0494  HKG TPE    33G  10:30  12:16  14:08
>   0495  TPE HKG    33G    14:59  16:43  17:13 06:43 17 Aug MO  O
>   18 Aug TU  G                 19 Aug WE  0697  HKG DEL    33G  19:05 
>   21:27       20 Aug TH              00:28  00:58 08:23 21 Aug FR  0694 
>   DEL HKG    33K  01:30  02:30  10:45  11:15 07:15    MED    HC
>   22 Aug SA  G                 23 Aug SU  G                 24 Aug MO  G
>   25 Aug TU  0767  HKG SGN    33E  07:30  08:40  10:15        0766  SGN
>   HKG    33E    11:20  15:10  15:40 08:10 26 Aug WE  G
>   27 Aug TH  G                 28 Aug FR  0699  HKG BOM    33G  16:20 
>   17:30  21:20  21:50 08:00 29 Aug SA  0696  BOM HKG    33G  21:30 
>   22:30       30 Aug SU              07:00  07:30 07:30 31 Aug MO  0564 
>   HKG TPE    330  12:00  13:10  14:55        0564  TPE KIX    330
>   16:05  20:00  20:30 07:30

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to get into an array the info from the text as described. eg : array[0] = '31 Jul FR 0135 HKG MEL 33K 18:00 19:44' , array[1]= '01 Aug SA 06:40 07:10 11:10' etc all the way to array[30] = '31 Aug MO 0564 HKG TPE 330 12:00 13:10 14:55 0564 TPE KIX 330
16:05 20:00 20:30 07:30'. thanks

Comment: this works :- https://regex101.com/r/pD9iT0/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex

```
(?=\d{2}\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\w{2})(.+?)(?:(?=\d{2}\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\w{2})|$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pD9iT0/4)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?=\d{2}\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\w{2}) #This is the same thing that you have given in question as regex
  (.+?) #Lazy matching to match all the characters between the present lookahead till the next lookahead. If we use greedy matching, it will match all the way to the last which we don't want
(?:  #Non-capturing group..I am using because of \z
  (?=\d{2}\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\w{2}) #Same lookahead as yours..It basically asserts the next position of the pattern you are searching..We want to capture whatever comes in between the two lookaheads
   | #Alternation
 $ #This is for capturing the last match because there will be no lookahead that follows the last one
)
```

**NOTE** :- I am using `s` modifier because we also want to match `\n` if it is there

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/(?=\\d{2}\\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s+\\w{2})(.+?)(?:(?=\\d{2}\\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s+\\w{2})|$)/s"; 
$str = "31 Jul FR 0135 HKG MEL 33K 18:00 19:44 01 Aug SA\n06:40 07:10 11:10 02 Aug SU 0134 MEL HKG 33K 06:40 07:37 15:21 15:51 11:11 03 Aug MO G 04 Aug TU 0905 HKG MNL 330 20:50 22:52 05 Aug WE 00:58\n0912 MNL HKG 330 08:32 10:36 11:06 14:16 06 Aug TH T2024\nP2 19:00 19:00 07 Aug FR 00:30 00:30 05:30\nT2314 2R 22:00 22:00 08 Aug SA 06:00 06:00 08:00 09 Aug SU G 10 Aug MO G 11 Aug TU R13 06:00 06:00 06:06 06:06 00:06 0699 HKG BOM\n33G 16:20 17:53 21:07 21:37 07:47 12 Aug WE 13 Aug TH RPT 00:00 00:00 02:45 02:45 02:45 14 Aug FR 0660 BOM HKG 33G 03:05 04:15 12:48 13:18 07:43 15 Aug SA R13\n06:00 06:00 11:23 11:23 05:23 T1514 CW 14:00 14:00 19:30 19:30 05:30 16 Aug SU 0494 HKG TPE 33G 10:30 12:16 14:08\n0495 TPE HKG 33G 14:59 16:43 17:13 06:43 17 Aug MO O\n18 Aug TU G 19 Aug WE 0697 HKG DEL 33G 19:05 21:27 20 Aug TH 00:28 00:58 08:23 21 Aug FR 0694 DEL HKG 33K 01:30 02:30 10:45 11:15 07:15 MED HC\n22 Aug SA G 23 Aug SU G 24 Aug MO G 25 Aug TU 0767 HKG SGN 33E 07:30 08:40 10:15 0766 SGN HKG 33E 11:20 15:10 15:40 08:10 26 Aug WE G\n27 Aug TH G 28 Aug FR 0699 HKG BOM 33G 16:20 17:30 21:20 21:50 08:00 29 Aug SA 0696 BOM HKG 33G 21:30 22:30 30 Aug SU 07:00 07:30 07:30 31 Aug MO 0564 HKG TPE 330 12:00 13:10 14:55 0564 TPE KIX 330\n16:05 20:00 20:30 07:30"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/wg9hkS)**

Comment: that is amazing. thankyou so much, is ther anyway you could explain some of it to me so i dont have to ask again like this. i would appreciate it . as they say, i want to learn to be a fisherman, i dont wish to just buy fish... thanks again

Comment: @Trevor ok i am adding the explanation..wait for few minutes

Comment: one more question. for some reason my code $str = "roster codes as before "; 

    $pattern = '/(?=\\d{2}\\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s+\\w{2})(.+?)(?:(?=\\d{2}\\s+[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s+\\w{2})|\\z)/s';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$str,$matches);
    print_r($matches); produces two arrays of same info ( multi array ) any help to make it just one?

Comment: @Trevor actually `$matches` returns array of array..If you use `$matches[0]`, it will be single dimensional..you can copy `$matches[0]` array if you want

Comment: thats great - thanks again for the help - i am learning slowly - cheers